# Regexp grab all text following last match

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to grab the text after the last number in the string and grab the whole string if it doesn't contain numbers.

The best regex I could come up with is:

```
([^\d\s]*)$
```

However I found that \s and \d aren't supported in mysql regexp rather [[:space:]] and not sure what \d is equivalent too.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
'1/2 Oz' returns 'Oz'
'2 3/4 Oz' returns 'Oz'
'As needed' returns 'As needed'
```

Comment: `[^[:digit:][:space:]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you will need:

```
/^.*?(\d+(?=\D*$)\s*)/
```

And just replace matched text with empty string `""`

PHP code:

```
$s = preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+(?=\D*$)\s*)/', '', 'Foo Oz');
//=> Foo Oz

$s = preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+(?=\D*$)\s*)/', '', '1/2 Oz');
//=> Oz
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/u887D7

Comment: This requires a digit.

Comment: @m.buettner: `preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+(?=\D*$)\s*)/', '', 'Foo Oz')` returns the whole string.

Comment: Oh right, you're replacing, not matching. Are you sure this translates to mysql?

Comment: Too be honest I'm not sure in which language OP is writing code. MySQL as far as I know doesn't have an equivalent of preg_replace in SQL.

Comment: It does have regular expressions though. And they don't support lookarounds.

Comment: It has regex only for matching a value. AFAIK OP cannot grab a text from a String using regex in SQL.

Comment: huh. in that case, I have no clue.

Comment: I was trying to do it in pure mysql but it seems for this case it would be easier to handle in PHP

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for your comment, I took the liberty of adding PHP tag in your question.

Comment: I tested it and it works great. The only problem is in my array i have dups. I'm trying to generate an HTML select with the query. I tried use strpos to see if the $s is in string but didn't work.

Comment: Nm, I had the args backwards. But if you have a more elegant solution that mine please share. Thans!

Comment: @Nick: If you post a new question with link to this Q&A and your proposed HTML generation code I am sure you will get few helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could simply avoid the class, and use a range instead:

```
[^0-9[:space:]]*$
```

But there is one for digits as well (which may actually include non-ASCII digits). The [documentation has a list of these](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). They are called [POSIX bracket expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) by the way.

```
[^[:digit:][:space:]]*$
```

However, the general problem with this approach is that it doesn't allow for spaces later on in the string (like the one between `As` and `needed`. To get those, but still avoid capturing trailing spaces after digits, make sure, the first character is neither space nor digit, then match the rest of the string as non-digits. In addition, make the whole thing optional, to ensure that it still works with strings ending in a digit.

```
([^[:digit:][:space:]][^:digit:]*)?$
```